# Make date field Date Picker only (disallow typed entry)

Tags: infopath

I have an InfoPath form on SharePoint Online (2013).

The date field has a date picker, but also allows people to type the date. i.e. 4/7/2015. This allows US users to type 4/7/2015 meaning 7th April, and for us in the UK to perhaps misinterpret it at 4th July.

How do I make it so they **must** use the Date Picker, and prevent them typing the date? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to make the format for the date picker meaningful for everyone, so you can make it: March 14, 1980. That way when they type a date, even by hand, it will be formatted this way, if that's not what they want, they will change it so it matches the formatted behavior.